# Гугл адсенс забанен давно. Есть ли смысл регистрировать аккаунт разработчика в плеймаркет для игр и приложений?

Tags: android, playmarket

стоит ли тратить силы и время на регистрацию аккаунта разработчика, делать приложения и мобильные игры, будет ли гул блокировать аккаунт разработчика, если адсенс ранее был забанен (давно, делал МФА и накосячил)? Есть ли для гугла связь между адсенс и аккаунтом в плеймаркете, не будут ли банить игры, а то и сам аккаунт? Стоит ли заморачиваться, у кого какие советы по этой ситуации? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Связь есть, банить будут. Вот тут почитайте про примеры и возможные решения: https://t.me/android_developers_ban

Comment: Печально, если так - беспредельщик конечно гугл... Забанил то МФА много лет назад за подозрительную активность - я то точно знаю, что по своим сайтам не кликал и не нагонял покупной трафик. Все только органика. Но забанили курвы, сколько не писал, не подавал - глухо. Теперь вот и в мобильном бизнесе смотрю, кислород перекпыт. А что, нет никакой альтернативы без плеймаркета? Слыхал, что если без гугла, то сразу в половину рынок и доходы уменьшаются - если на другие сайты закидывать приложения. Или есть какой- то выход?

Comment: Про половину - преувеличение. Гугл около 90% рынка занимает. Засим - выхода нет. Только если на китайский рынок работать, где Гугл забанен. Ну или банить Гугл у себя в стране